# Don't return posts where the ACF meta date subfield has passed (WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress, date, advanced-custom-fields

I have this query which returns a list of post titles for the current event.

```
<ul class="event-category-list no-margin no-list-style">
<?php 
    $current_category = get_queried_object();
    $args = array(
        'post_type'         => 'event',
        'posts_per_page'    => -1,
        'tax_query'         => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'event-type',
                'field'    => 'term_id',
                'terms'    => $current_category->term_id,
            ),
        ),
    );
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();

    ?>

        <li>
            <?php echo the_title(); ?>
        </li>

    <?php endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
</ul>
```

It works fine.

Also, each post has an ACF date repeater subfield called `event_date` (format is Ymd) which can have **one or more** dates.

**What also needs to happen**

I need my query to **not** return posts where all instances of the `event_date` are in the past.

**Explaining by example**

Let's say the event is a Foo Fighters concert, and it's over three dates: 20230726, 20230727 and 20230728 (the ACF date repeater subfield `event_date` has those three dates).

[image]

If all of those dates are in the past, the post title should not be returned.

Comment: ACF stores repeater fields with an index in the key name, so you need to manipulate the SQL of the generated query for this to work, https://wpza.net/using-meta_query-with-acf-repeater-field/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of working with an ACF repeater fields directly in a meta_query (which would need a more complex SQL queries, such as using a `JOIN` operation with a subquery), you can consider:

- fetching all events without filtering them by the event_date subfield in the query itself,
- and then filters the results using a loop in PHP.

```
<ul class="event-category-list no-margin no-list-style">
<?php
    $current_category = get_queried_object();
    $today = date('Ymd'); // Get today's date in the same format as the ACF subfield

    $args = array(
        'post_type'         => 'event',
        'posts_per_page'    => -1,
        'tax_query'         => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'event-type',
                'field'    => 'term_id',
                'terms'    => $current_category->term_id,
            ),
        ),
    );

    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
        // Loop through the event_date repeater subfield
        $event_dates = get_field('event_date');
        $is_future_event = false;

        foreach ($event_dates as $event_date) {
            if ($event_date >= $today) {
                $is_future_event = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        // Only display the title if the event has at least one date today or in the future
        if ($is_future_event) {
    ?>

        <li>
            <?php echo the_title(); ?>
        </li>

    <?php 
        } 
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
</ul>
```

In the functions.php file of your theme (`wp-content/themes/my-theme/functions.php`), you can add:

```php
function wpza_replace_event_date_field( $where ) {
    $where = str_replace( "meta_key = 'event_date_$", "meta_key LIKE 'event_date_%", $where );
    return $where;
}
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'wpza_replace_event_date_field' );
```

The `wpza_replace_event_date_field()` function is hooked to the [`posts_where` filter using the `add_filter()` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/posts_where/) in the `functions.php` file

When a new `WP_Query` is created and executed, WordPress internally builds the SQL query. During this process, it triggers the `posts_where` filter, and any functions hooked to this filter will be called.
In this case, the `wpza_replace_event_date_field()` function will be called, and it will modify the SQL `WHERE` clause to search for all meta keys that match the pattern `event_date_{index}_event_date`.
By doing so, it ensures that the SQL query includes all rows with keys that represent the `event_date` subfield of the ACF repeater.

The loop (`while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ... endwhile;`)  checks if the event has at least one date today or in the future, and if so, it displays the title of the event.
The indirect effect of the `wpza_replace_event_date_field()` function is that the `WP_Query` will return posts with `event_date` subfields that match the criteria defined in the `meta_query`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `meta_query` param for compare dates:

```
<ul class="event-category-list no-margin no-list-style">
<?php
    $current_category = get_queried_object();
    $today = date('Ymd');
    $args = array(
        'post_type'         => 'event',
        'posts_per_page'    => -1,
        'tax_query'         => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'event-type',
                'field'    => 'term_id',
                'terms'    => $current_category->term_id,
            ),
        ),
        'meta_query'    => array(
            'relation'      => 'AND',
            array(
                'key'       => 'event_date',
                'value'     => $today,
                'compare'   => '>='
            )
        )
    );
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();

    ?>

        <li>
            <?php echo the_title(); ?>
        </li>

    <?php endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
</ul>
```